# How to add and use custom js file in Angular 2 App in TypeScript components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings, external-dependencies

I have pretty standard Angular 2 App created with angular-cli

I want to be able to use custom .js file with it.
Simplified mocked version looks like that:

```
'use strict';

var testingThing = testingThing || {};

testingThing.Client = function (name) {
    var self = this;
    console.log(name);

    this.parseUri = function (str) {
        console.log(str);
        return str;
    };

    return this;
};

// Node environment module
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    module.exports = testingThing;
}
```

I'm struggling how can I use it inside typescript component.

I tried this (or similar, tried also different things)

```
export class TestService {

  something: any;

  constructor() {
    this.something = new testingThing.Client();
    var huh = this.something.new("test name");
    testingThing.parseUri("testParse");
  }

}
```

I tried to generate typing for it

```
declare namespace testingThing{

    class Client {
        new (name : string): /* testingThing.Client */ any;
    }

    function parseUri(str : any): any;
}
```

but then I got errors in console, that testingThing is not defined.

```
 Cannot read property 'Client' of undefined
```

When I tried to import it, it says that testingThing is not a module.

I did added myCustom.js to angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
        "./myCustom.js"
      ],
```

I tried couple of different approaches from internet, so I'm completely out of ideas now, what I'm doing wrong. Is it my usage of it, my typing definition, or anything else.

I hope answer is kind of obvious for folks more use to frontend programming, but I'm stacked now.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it work, so if you have same problem as I had and posted this Q here, then hope it will help you too :) (not sure if it's the right way, but it works for me). It was hit and miss exploring. Lots of misses and one hit at the end:

1. Include your custom script in `<script></script>` tags in index.html like this:

   ```
   <script src="./myCustom.js"></script>
   ```
2. Typing should be changed:

   - class instead of interface
   - constructor instead of new method (also you need to remove return value declaration)

```
declare namespace testingThing 
{

      class Client {

        constructor(name: string)
      }

      function testFunction(str: any): string;}
```

And then the sample usage will be:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  somethingElse: any;

  constructor() {
    this.somethingElse = new testingThing.Client("constructor");
    console.log(this.somethingElse);
    this.somethingElse.testFunction("test call to function inside");
  }

}
```

Without any imports, "require" or variable declarations.

Also, you should remove from angular-cli.json you library from scripts section (or not to include it anyway). It is not needed.